# Show that $ \frac{e^{\theta(x_0 + ... + x_n)}}{E[e^{\theta x_1}]}$ is a martingale

Tags: probability, statistics, stochastic-processes, martingales

Let $X_0, X_1, ...$ i.i.d random variables.

Show that $$M_n = \frac{e^{\theta(x_0 + ... + x_n)}}{E[e^{\theta x_1}]}$$

is a martingale to respecto to $F^S$

I'm trying to prove that $E[M_n]<\infty$ and I know that somehow I how to use that they are identical and independent random variables but I'm not sure how to deal with the denominator. Any suggestions would be great!

Comment: This is very straightforward. Write down $E[M_{n+1} \mid \mathcal{F}_n]$. The denominator and terms involving $X_0, \ldots, X_n$ can be pulled out of the conditional expectation, leaving a term involving $X_{n+1}$ in the expectation. But since $X_{n+1}$ is independent of $\mathcal{F}_n$, this is the same as an unconditional expectation and cancels with the denominator.

Comment: The denominator in $M_n$ need not be finite. You are missing some hypothesis.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @angryavian ! So the term $E\left[\frac{e^{\theta x_1}}{E[e^{\theta x_1}]}\right]$ can be written like this $E\left[e^{\theta x_1}\right]*\frac{1}{E[e^{\theta x_1}}$? Or we end up with $E\left[e^{\theta x_1}\right]*\frac{1}{E[E[e^{\theta x_1}]]}$?

Comment: BTW I think there is typo in the numerator it should be $e^{(\theta(x_0 + ... + x_n)/n}$ unless mistaken

Comment: @TheBridge The question is like that, there is no typo. It is not possible to show that is a martingale?

Comment: Well as $x_i$s are iid the expectation of the denominator is $E[e^{(\theta(x_0 + ... + x_n)}]=\Pi_{i=1}^n E[e^{(\theta.x_i)} ]=E[e^{(\theta.x_1)} ]^n$ so the sum should be averaged for the martingale property of $M_n$ to hold.